# How can I change the custom toolbar name in the add in tab in Excel?

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0, vsto, excel-addins

My application is an add-in to the MS excel,
and it has a name with "custom toolbar". How can I change the 
custom toolbar name to any other name.
I am not using any Ribbon class / Ribbon XML.
It is created using CommandBar,CommandButton, FaceID
but only i need the renaming.

I am using .net 4.0 VS WinForms.

Please can someone help me in this?
Thanks in advance. The code snippet is as follows

```
  public void OnConnection(object application, Extensibility.ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst, ref System.Array custom)
    {           
        try
        {
        //    Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBar toolBar = null;
        //    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = null;
        //    if (application is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)
        //    {
        //        excelApp = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)application;
        //    }
        //    if (excelApp != null)
        //    {
        //        toolBar = AddExcelToolbar(excelApp, "MyApp");
        //    }

            if (key == null || key.GetValue("Enable").ToString() == "1")
            {

                Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                m_objAddInInstance = (Microsoft.Office.Core.COMAddIn)addInInst;
                if (application is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)
                 {
                    m_objOfficeComponent = new ExcelComponent((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)application);

                }
                else
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Hi");

                }

                sw.Stop();

                    MyMessageBox.Log("sw.ElapsedMilliseconds : ",       sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
                 MyMessageBox.Log("sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds : ",sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString());
                  MyMessageBox.Log("sw.ElapsedTicks : ", sw.ElapsedTicks.ToString());
                //m_objOfficeComponent.Init();
           }

        }
```

The screen shot is show below
[image]

Comment: Just curious, but if your project is an MS Excel add-in already then why not use the Ribbon class?

Comment: rwisch45 - I don't know why it is still renamed as custom toolbar, in registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->Software->Microsoft->Office->Excel->Addins->MyApp.Connect is made guess that sits in the addins tab of excel.

Comment: rwisch45 - I have added the code snippet above , this method is in the connect class.

Answer (score 0):

I havent tested this but it might work with little tweak

```
foreach (CommandBar cmdBar in application.CommandBars)
        {
            foreach (CommandBarControl control in cmdBar.Controls)
            {
                if (control.Type == MsoControlType.msoControlButtonPopup)
                {
                    control.accName = "New name";
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: this is the specific name given to the particular button right?

Comment: @roopinin Yes thats right, I have provided you the outline. Globals.ThisAddin.Application.CommandBars provides you the collection of CommandBar and again you can iterate through the Controls to find the one you required.